Stripe doesn't believe client_secret is created with my account
I'm attempting to setup stripe connect payments on svelte-kit, however stripe keeps returning an error:

The client_secret provided does not match any associated PaymentIntent on this account. Ensure the publishable key used belongs to the same account that created the PaymentIntent.

I've triple-checked that the client secret was created with the matching secret key to my public key, I've also attempted to try a sandbox account instead of a test environment and still get the same error.
This is the sever code for generating a client_secret:
import { SECRET_STRIPE_KEY } from '$env/static/private';
const stripe = new Stripe(SECRET_STRIPE_KEY, {
    apiVersion: "2024-11-20.acacia" as "2024-10-28.acacia", // This is a type assertion
});

export async function GET() {

    const ticket_price = 45;
    const application_fee = 1;

    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: ticket_price,
        currency: 'gbp',
        application_fee_amount: application_fee,
        automatic_payment_methods: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }, {
        stripeAccount: 'acct_1QWcgoDArWfcz7re',
    });

    return json({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret
    }, { status: 200 });
}

This is the part of the client side that uses svelte-stipe and stripe-js to create a payment form:
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js'
    import type { Stripe, StripeElements } from '@stripe/stripe-js'
    import { Elements, PaymentElement, LinkAuthenticationElement, Address } from 'svelte-stripe'
    import { PUBLIC_STRIPE_KEY } from '$env/static/public';

    let stripe: null | Stripe = null
    let clientSecret : null | string = null
    let elements: StripeElements | null | undefined
    let processing = false

    onMount(async () => {
        stripe = await loadStripe(PUBLIC_STRIPE_KEY, { apiVersion: "2024-11-20.acacia" as "2024-10-28.acacia" })
        clientSecret = await createPaymentIntent()
    })

    async function createPaymentIntent() {
        const response = await fetch('/api/stripe/payment', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        })

        const { clientSecret } = await response.json()
        return clientSecret
    }

    async function submit() {
        // ...
    }

</script>

{#if clientSecret !== null}
    <Elements
        {stripe}
        {clientSecret}
        theme="flat"
        labels="floating"
        bind:elements
    >
        <form on:submit|preventDefault={submit}>
        <LinkAuthenticationElement />
        <PaymentElement />
        <Address mode="billing" />

        <button disabled={processing}>
            {#if processing}
            Processing...
            {:else}
            Pay
            {/if}
        </button>
        </form>
    </Elements>
{:else}
    Loading...
{/if}

At first, I thought it might be an issue with stripe-svelte, however while looking at the network request all the parameters are correct. I triple-checked the key and also the client_secret, so is it just a Stripe issue?
https://api.stripe.com/v1/elements/sessions?client_secret=pi_3QWcxADArWfcz7re023mkEqp_secret_mHQ6ErNxsy61qqAAp57FD1rIT&key=pk_test_69buoGS6vl82TpptRDix1WEr00LnbLWpxw&_stripe_version=2024-11-20.acacia&type=payment_intent&locale=en-US&referrer_host=localhost:5173&expand[0]=payment_method_preference.payment_intent.payment_method&stripe_js_id=bb0bb448-9ebf-46c9-b6e5-77e60c7f4016

client_secret=pi_3QWcxADArWfcz7re023mkEqp_secret_mHQ6ErNxsy61qqAAp57FD1rIT
key=pk_test_69buoGS6vl82TpptRDix1WEr00LnbLWpxw

Here is the error response from stripe:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The client_secret provided does not match any associated PaymentIntent on this account. Ensure the publishable key used belongs to the same account that created the PaymentIntent.",
    "param": "client_secret",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_Gf29tN9FjPAYJe?t=1734350353",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}

Checking the Stripe logs, you can see the failed request, but not the request to create the client secret.

Update
I removed the "stripeAccount" from the paymentIntent creation and it now doesn't show the error however it now doesn't work as a connected payment so I'm assuming i have to use the secret and public of the connected stripe account?

The issue was in the client side, i forgot to add "stripeAccount" to the options on the "loadStripe"
https://docs.stripe.com/connect/direct-charges?platform=web&ui=elements&client=react#configure-elements-provider
